# How to find edge pixels in shader?

Tags: hlsl, direct3d

Is it possible to understand in the shader that pixel is on the edge of the geometry?

[image]

Or at least understand that pixel on the edge of the triangle?

[image]

Maybe ddx()/ddy() can help?

Comment: Keywords to search for are "edge detection".
Methods vary depending on whether you can control the background or not, whether you have a depth buffer or not. See previous questions
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46832139/how-can-i-check-whether-a-fragment-lies-on-the-edge-of-a-texture
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27731963/glsl-fragment-shader-detect-that-the-current-fragment-is-on-the-edge-of-a-polyg
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74988588/what-are-the-common-used-fast-edge-detection-algorithm-using-gpu-shaderglsl-hl

Answer (score 2):

Possible but relatively tricky, and you gonna need a geometry shader. They are almost always available in Direct3D: the last GPU with feature level < 11.0 was Intel Sandy Bridge from 2011, computers don’t usually live that long. However, availability in GL and especially GLES varies.

**Edges of Triangles**

In the geometry shader, generate `float2` for each vertex of the triangle, with the values [ 1, 0 ], [ 0, 1 ] and [ 0, 0 ] for the 3 vertices of the triangle.

Then in the pixel shader, use the following HLSL function for edge detection, untested:

```hlsl
inline bool detectEdge( in float2 bary2 )
{
    // Compute minimum of these barycentric coordinates
    // The third one is redundant because they add up to 1.0
    float minBary = min( bary2.x, bary2.y );
    minBary = min( minBary, 1.0 - ( bary2.x + bary2.y ) );
    // Compute screen-space derivative of that variable
    float w = fwidth( minBary );
    // We want to return true for 1 pixels-wide line on the edge
    // Edges are shared by 2 triangles, each triangle needs 0.5 pixel wide line
    return ( minBary * 2 ) < w;
}
```

**Edges of Geometry**

Your first question is more complicated.
One possible approach, add one more vertex attribute of type `DXGI_FORMAT_R8_UINT`. Set these bytes to 1 for vertices on the edge of the mesh, 0 for the rest of them.

Pass these integers from vertex to geometry shader.
There, you can find out which edges of the triangle are on the edge of the geometry:

```hlsl
inline uint outerEdgesBitmap( uint v0, uint v1, uint v2 )
{
    uint res = 0;
    if( v0 != 0 && v1 != 0 )
        res = 1;    // v0-v1 edge is external
    if( v1 != 0 && v2 != 0 )
        res |= 2;   // v1-v2 edge is external
    if( v2 != 0 && v0 != 0 )
        res |= 4;   // v2-v0 edge is external
    return res;
}
```

With that bitmap passed down the graphic pipeline, you can detect pixels on the outer edges of the geometry in the pixel shader:

```hlsl
inline bool detectEdge( in float2 bary2, uint outerBitmap )
{
    float minBary = 1.0;
    if( 0 != ( outerBitmap & 1 ) )
        minBary = bary2.x;
    if( 0 != ( outerBitmap & 2 ) )
        minBary = min( minBary, bary2.y );
    if( 0 != ( outerBitmap & 4 ) )
        minBary = min( minBary, 1.0 - ( bary2.x + bary2.y ) );

    // For open edges, we want the entire 1-pixel wide line inside the triangle
    return minBary < fwidth( minBary );
}
```

P.S. I haven’t tested these HLSL functions, but I have used a similar approach in the past, it works.

Comment: Nice, but in my case I have only Vertex and Pixel shaders( And solution with addition attribute also don't for my case